# How can I install IRremote library for Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, arduino

I want to control an IR Led hooked up to an Arduino, with an app
on the computer.

So I went to download the IRremote library that comes with a Node.js module (https://github.com/AnthonyMyatt/IRremote)

The problem is that when I dropped the files (as stated in other posts on how to install a module for Node.js manually), and I call the 'require' function,
I get an error when running the program.

```
Debugger listening to port 5858
module.js:355
Module._extensions[extension](this,filename);
                              ^
Error: no errorc:\users\hp\node_modules\irlib\build\Release\IRremote.node
    at Error (native)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\users\hp\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Leap motion_Arduino Test\Leap motion_Arduino Test\server.js:1:72
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
Press any key to continue...
```

The first lines of my server.js are:

```
var IR = require("irlib");
var webSocket = require('ws'),
```

Where irlib is the folder name I gave to the one containing the module.

I seriously have no idea, but I suspect there is something wrong with the library (file structure isn't exactly the same as, for instance, johnny-five or ws).

Can someone tell me how can I install this IRremote library in Node.js?

I'm a student and I like doing things with Arduino
as a hobby. I've been doing this for about a year,
but i'm still a newbie.

I recently started out with Node.js, because I wanted to make a
project which involved communication between the Arduino and the
computer.

Comment: Just an observation. The first thing you should do in a question is briefly summarize your problem in as few sentences as possible. This will allow answerers searching for a question to answer to see what you are asking without even clicking on your question. Currently, all we see is your introduction of who you are, which doesn't say anything about this question.

Comment: Can we see the first couple lines of server.js?

Comment: Updated post with the first lines of my server.js.

Comment: And, when you manually installed it, you copied it into your node_modules folder, right?

Comment: Yes; In fact, the program actually finds the package (else it would throw the package not found error). Also, I've just checked that if you open the IRremote.node file (which I suppose its the main file), a cmd window appears and disappears really fast, but I've managed to read an error:no error too.